# "Like" a post using Facebook open graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This doesn't work for me.  I do have publish permissions and I am able to post messages to the wall.  Any idea if liking needs a different permission?

```
FB.api("/12345/likes", 'post', function (response) {
            if (response === true) {
                //alert("done!");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I've seen a few questions about creating likes using the graph API before and the consensus I think was it isn't possible - or at least I haven't seen how.

Comment: Yeah I read around and I didn't find anything concrete. But while it seemed clear that you cannot like "pages", liking "posts" seemed like something you could do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs say it's possible, but in reality it can't be done. This is a known reported bug:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10714